# what's the QUALITY_HIGH and the QUALITY_LOW mean ？

Tags: android, video, camera, resolution

There is a quality list in the class CamcorderProfile.

public static final int QUALITY_HIGH:

Quality level corresponding to the highest available resolution.
Constant Value: 1

public static final int QUALITY_LOW

Quality level corresponding to the lowest available resolution.
Constant Value: 0

...

(QUALITY_1080P ,QUALITY_720P,QUALITY_480P,QUALITY_CIF ,QUALITY_HIGH,QUALITY_LOW, QUALITY_QCIF,QUALITY_QVGA,etc.)

the explanation of QUALITY_HIGH ：Quality level corresponding to **the highest available resolution.**

the explanation of QUALITY_LOW ：Quality level corresponding to **the lowest available resolution.**

The upper quality list is only for android original source code. The company like the MediaTek maybe add the other quality(such as QUALITY_MTK_HIGH) into the class.

So I have a question, what's **the highest available resolution.** and **the lowest available resolution.** mean?

Should we concern the added quality by other Mobile-phone-chip-makers? Or the available resolution is only about the android original quality list?

I am using android 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's decided by the implemention of the MediaProfiles.cpp .

Answer (score 0):

QUALITY_HIGH and QUALITY_LOW refers to the highest or lowest available video quality supported by your device

Comment: what's the available video quality corresponding to ? Image there is a quality:QUALITY_MTK_FINE ,constant Value is 11, and the resolution is 1280X720. We don't support the QUALITY_1080P ,QUALITY_720P ,but only support QUALITY_480P,QUALITY_CIF ,QUALITY_HIGH,QUALITY_LOW, QUALITY_QCIF,QUALITY_QVGA. So I want to know , what's the highest video quality.  QUALITY_MTK_FINE or  QUALITY_480P ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int QUALITY_HIGH
public static final int QUALITY_LOW
```

According to android docs quality level will be the highest/lowest available resolution(as per camera resolutions) which exactly means the `preview sizes, bitrates, audio/video encoder, output format(e.g 3gp, mp4)` and many more based on the `HIGH/LOW` quality your recorded file size and quality will be increase/decrease. Based on your requirements you can use any of the either.

Comment: I don't think so. I think the QUALITY_HIGH corresponding to the highest available video quality supported by my device . Never mind with the preview sizes ,etc. But I am not sure the supported list whether including the Mobile-phone-chip-makers's own quality.